# Ruby UNIXServer with Node.js client and chunked data

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, node.js, unix-socket

I've this Ruby server that uses a Unix Socket:

```
require 'socket'
require 'json'

server = UNIXServer.new('/tmp/ciccio.sock')
loop do
  sock = server.accept
  loop do
    begin
      data = sock.recv(1024)
      break if data.empty?
      # calculate a response
      response = {supermega: "very long json" * 10000}
      sock.write(response.to_json)
      sock.flush
    rescue Errno::EPIPE, Errno::ENOTCONN
      break
    end
  end
end
```

And I've this client in JavaScript that uses node.js [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) api:

```
Net = require('net');

var client = Net.connect({ path: '/tmp/ciccio.sock' }, () => {
    console.log('write data');
    client.write('hello world!');
});

client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    // do something with json
});

client.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');
});

client.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error.toString());
});
```

The problem is that if the data is big (over about 8193 characters) `JSON.parse` fail because `data` is chunked. How can I get the whole json as string and then parse it?

Answer (score 0):

You should only parse the JSON when you have received all of the text. Try this in the client.

```
Net = require('net');

var client = Net.connect({ path: '/tmp/ciccio.sock' }, () => {
    console.log('write data');
    client.write('hello world!');
});

// this will contain the whole JSON String
var totalString = '';

client.on('data', (data) => {
    // progressively add the chunks to totalString
    var chunk = data.toString();
    console.log(chunk);
    totalString += chunk;
});

client.on('end', () => {
    // now you may parse the JSON
    var json = JSON.parse(totalString);
    totalString = ''; // release totalString to the garbage collector
    // now do something with json
    console.log('end');
});

client.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error.toString());
});
```

***Note*** this could be done much more efficiently if you had some way of predicting the size of the data. String appending with `+=` is very inefficient.

Comment: The `end` event is never emitted in my example... I'm using net api (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_event_end), not http api (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback)

Comment: @Pioz Now looking at your Ruby server, you never call `sock.close`. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: I don't want close my socket, I want to keep it opened... I don't want make a connection for every message.

Comment: @Pioz Ok so the thing you are calling `sock` is not a socket. It's a temporary connection on that socket. There will be no problem with closing it. Your AF_UNIX socket is held in the variable you have named `server`.